# Finding the instantaneous rate of change

Tags: calculus

I need clarification as to how to do this question:

> It takes $200$ minutes to fill a water tank. The volume of water $V$ litres, after $t$ minutes, is given by $V = 100t - \frac 1 4 t^2$, for $0 \le t \le 200$. Find the instantaneous rate of change of volume when $t = 100$.

Comment: When you pose a problem here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change of rate $= \frac{V(t_1+t)-V(t_1)}{(t_1+t)-t_1}.$

Instantaneous cahnge of rate $= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{V(t_1+t)-V(t_1)}{(t_1+t)-t_1}\ = \ \frac{d}{dt}V(t)\big|_{t=t_1}.$

So, in your case:-
$$ \frac{d}{dt}V(t)=100-\frac{t}{2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}V(t)\big|_{t=100} =100-50=50 \text{ liters/minutes}.$$

Comment: how did you get to 100-t/2? I got 100-1/4.t

Comment: wait never mind I just noticed what I did wrong, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The "instantaneous rate of change"
is just the derivative
with respect to time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be translated to a mathematical one, which requires us to find the derivative of the function $t \mapsto 100t - \frac{1}{4}t^{2}: [0,200] \to \mathbb{R}$ at $t := 100$.

The instantaneous rate of change is a physical interpretation of derivative.